# "Airfoil" - why it is called "foil"

Tags: etymology

What is origin of word airfoil (e.g. wings of the airplane)? Why it has part "foil", which is a very thin metal sheet.

"Dictionary.com Unabridged" says only "Origin: 1920–25; air 1 + foil 2" (© Random House), and "foil 2" is defined by them exactly as thin metal, e.g. aluminium foil (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(metal)).

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the notion of a **foil** as a leaf shaped curve formed by the cusping of an arch or circle.  (See also the definition of a foil as a blade for fencing.)

An [Airfoil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfoil) is a similarly leaf-shaped curve or blade that is used to push/cut the air.  Look at the cross sections of common airfoil shapes, and you will see the similarity to the shape of a leaf.

**Foil** is derived from the latin *folium* meaning leaf.

Incidentally (and not directly related to the rest of the answer), that is the same etymology of the term gold leaf to mean a thin gold foil (leaf = foil).